# How do I create a dependent dropdown list in Yii2?

Tags: database, list, yii2, dropdown

In this dependent dropdown list, I'm not gonna read it from a database but a bunch of constant values.

In my model:

```
   const ASSET_ACCOUNT = 1;
   const LIABILITY_ACCOUNT = 2;
   const FUND_BALANCE_ACCOUNT = 3;
   const CURRENT_ASSETS = 100;
   const PROPERTY_AND_EQUIPMENT = 200;
   const OTHER_ASSETS = 300;
   const CURRENT_LIABILITIES = 400;
   const FUND_BALANCE = 500;

public function getAccountType() {
      return array (self::ASSET_ACCOUNT=>'Asset',self::LIABILITY_ACCOUNT=>'Liabilty',self::FUND_BALANCE_ACCOUNT=>'Fund Balance');
    }

public function getAccountTypeLabel($account_type) {
  if ($account_type==self::ASSET_ACCOUNT) {
    return 'Asset';
    }
  if ($account_type==self::LIABILITY_ACCOUNT) {
    return 'Liabilty';      
    }
  if ($account_type==self::FUND_BALANCE_ACCOUNT) {
    return 'Fund Balance';    
    }
}
```

In my view:

```
<?=
$form->field($model, 'account_type')->dropDownList($model->getAccountType(), 
         ['prompt'=>'- Choose Account Type-']) ?>

<?=
$form->field($model, 'second_type')->dropDownList($model->getSecondType(), 
         ['prompt'=>'- Choose Second Type-']) ?>
```

So what I am trying to do is to get the second_type dependent on the account_type dropdown list. They read values from the constants and then I save it to the database. So for example, when the account_type is ASSET, the second_type dropdown list will list the options CURRENT ASSETS and PROPERTY AND EQUIPMENT. Then save the values 100 or 200 in the database. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Use [Kartik dep drop](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/depdrop) and [Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBm3z3qIbR4).

Comment: THe Kartik ded drop is reading from a database. How do I just read it from the model?

Comment: Kartik DepDrop is not reading from database. All you need is add a method to your model that returns subcategories for category and add an action to controller that uses this method and returns result for DepDrop.